# How to return javascript content based on request params

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to return javascript content for client, base on url params. The content of javascript is difference for clients.
Example: Request URL: http://example.com/static/js/sites/123456.js
will return:

```
function() {
   var configs = {
      site: 123456,
   }
}
```

This link show exactly what I want:
https://static.hotjar.com/c/hotjar-14.js?sv=6

You can change hotjar-14 to hotjar-15, hotjar-100, hotjar-1000,... to see the JS content will change too.

Comment: Hello and welcome! I do not understand the question. Can you please [edit] to add more information about what input you want to take and what output it should produce?

Comment: Thanks, I've add example on my question

Answer (score 0):

You can simply spin up an express JS server that returns something like this:

```
app.get("/static/js/sites/:site.js", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200)
     .send(`
function() {
   var configs = {
      site: ${req.params.site},
   }
}`);
});
```

This will send you the right content based on the `site` param.

Answer (score -1):

Seems you need JSONP protocol. Try search on this side node.js+jsonp

Comment: That's too much for this.